# Python code for VMware OVF export to local disk in vshpere client

Tags: python, python-3.x, vmware, vsphere, esxi

I am trying to write code that will power off the VM and export the OVF template of the VM to my local disk on the Vsphere client and then power on the VM.

```
import pyVim
import atexit
import ssl
from pyVim import connect
from pyVmomi import vim

def vconnect():
    try:
        s = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
        s.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
        # Connect to a cluster or host
        #service_instance = connect.SmartConnect(host="Host IP", user="Host user", pwd="Host Pswd", port=443, sslContext=s)
        atexit.register(connect.Disconnect, service_instance)
        content = service_instance.RetrieveContent()
        container = content.rootFolder
        viewType = [vim.VirtualMachine]
        recursive = True
        containerView = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(container, viewType, recursive)
        childern = containerView.view
        #print(childern)
        
        for child in childern:
            summary = child.summary
            print(child.name, "=" ,child.runtime.powerState)
            #print(summary.config.name)
            #print("---")
            vm_name = child.name
            if vm_name == 'Test 51.48':
                print("-------")
                print("VM : {}".format(vm_name))
                print("Powering off VM {}".format(vm_name))
                #Power on the VM
                try:
                    child.PowerOff()

                    print("VM powered off")
                except Exception as e:
                    print("{} Power off failed because : {}".format(vm_name, e))
                #Take OVF backup to local disk
                try:
                    #Need the Backup code
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Back up failed because ", e)
                #Power on the VM
                try:
                    child.PowerOn()

                    print("VM powered off")
                except Exception as e:
                    print("{} Power off failed because : {}".format(vm_name, e))
                print("-------")
    except Exception as e:
        print("SSL connection failed because ", e)

vconnect()
```

New to python scripting.
need to add the backup script in the above code.
How do I take the OVF backup with the code?